# Combobox не сортирует на кириллице Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, winforms, visual-studio

уважаемые программисты! Проблема такая:

Не могу понять, так как плохо разбираюсь в программировании и коде. Возникла проблема с сортировкой comboBox. Сначала были проблемы с кириллицей, буквы отображались как "?". Поставил nvarchar в таблицах БД и написал следующий код комбобокса:

```
private void comboBox_search_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectQuerry = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProdCat=N'"+comboBox_search.SelectedValue.ToString()+"'";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuerry, dBCon.GetCon());
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);
    dataGridView_product.DataSource = table;
}
```

Проблема в том что сортировка работает только на английском языке: https://ibb.co/pZZ1JPg
Так же пример: https://ibb.co/twGv0gM

База данных если что заполнена полностью и создавалась она средствами Visual Studio. Подскажите пожалуйста что можно с этим сделать? Пробовал в строке подключения добавлять разные кодировки, в свойствах что-то прописывал, пробовал много чего уже даже и не вспомню так как проект старый и мне нужно его воскресить. Могу записать видео или скинуть проект полностью, или скинуть нужные строчки кода.

Код формы с проблемой:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Mini_Market_Management_System
{
    public partial class ProductForm : Form
    {
        DBConnect dBCon = new DBConnect();
        public ProductForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_category_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CategoryForm category = new CategoryForm();
            category.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void ProductForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "minimarketdbDataSet.Category". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
            this.categoryTableAdapter.Fill(this.minimarketdbDataSet.Category);
            // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "minimarketdbDataSet.Product". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
            this.productTableAdapter.Fill(this.minimarketdbDataSet.Product);
            getCategory();
            getTable();


        }

        private void getCategory()
        {
            string selectQuerry = "SELECT * FROM Category";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuerry, dBCon.GetCon());
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            comboBox_category.DataSource = table;
            comboBox_category.ValueMember = "CatName";
            comboBox_search.DataSource = table;
            comboBox_search.ValueMember = "CatName";
        }

        private void getTable()
        {
            string selectQuerry = "SELECT * FROM Product";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuerry, dBCon.GetCon());
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            dataGridView_product.DataSource = table;
        }

        private void clear()
        {
            TextBox_id.Clear();
            TextBox_name.Clear();
            TextBox_price.Clear();
            TextBox_qty.Clear();
            comboBox_category.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void button_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Product VALUES(" + TextBox_id.Text + ",N'" + TextBox_name.Text + "'," + TextBox_price.Text + "," + TextBox_qty.Text + ",N'" + comboBox_category.Text + "')";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, dBCon.GetCon());
                dBCon.OpenCon();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Product Added Successfully", "Add Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                dBCon.CloseCon();
                getTable();
                clear();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (TextBox_id.Text == "" || TextBox_name.Text == "" || TextBox_price.Text == "" || TextBox_qty.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Missing Information", "Missing Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else
                {

                    string updateQuery = "UPDATE Product SET ProdName=N'" + TextBox_name.Text + "',ProdPrice=" + TextBox_price.Text + ",ProdQty=" + TextBox_qty.Text + ",ProdCat=N'" + comboBox_category.Text + "'WHERE ProdId=" + TextBox_id.Text + "";
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, dBCon.GetCon());
                    dBCon.OpenCon();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Product Updated Successfully", "Update Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    dBCon.CloseCon();
                    getTable();
                    clear();
                }
            }   
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

     

        private void dataGridView_product_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox_id.Text = dataGridView_product.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            TextBox_name.Text = dataGridView_product.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            TextBox_price.Text = dataGridView_product.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            TextBox_qty.Text = dataGridView_product.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            comboBox_category.SelectedValue = dataGridView_product.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        }

        private void button_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (TextBox_id.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Missing Information", "Missing Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    string deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM Product WHERE ProdId=" + TextBox_id.Text + "";
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(deleteQuery, dBCon.GetCon());
                    dBCon.OpenCon();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Product Deleted Successfully", "Delete Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    dBCon.CloseCon();
                    getTable();
                    clear();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button_Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getTable();
        }

        private void comboBox_search_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selectQuerry = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProdCat=N'"+comboBox_search.SelectedValue.ToString()+"'";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuerry, dBCon.GetCon());
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            dataGridView_product.DataSource = table;
        }

        private void label_exit_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label_exit.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void label_exit_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label_exit.ForeColor = Color.Goldenrod;
        }

        private void label_logout_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label_logout.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        private void label_logout_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label_logout.ForeColor = Color.Goldenrod;
        }

        private void label_logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginForm login = new LoginForm();
            login.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void label_exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button_seller_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SellerForm seller = new SellerForm();
            seller.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void button_selling_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SellingForm selling = new SellingForm();
            selling.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void TextBox_id_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TextBox_name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView_product_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox_category_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox_search_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Может быть недоглядел, но а где происходит-то сортировка?